# Reverse number using only loops;no Arrays,convert to String just beginner…Bug:Zero

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse random number from 1 to 9999, and got stuck with a bug zero:

**Example:** 23100 is the random number. my output is 132 but the solution is 00132

Since I still don't know Arrays, convert to String(manipulation), object solution etc…. I couldn't find a beginner-level solution for this problem.
Since this page helped me a lot, I decided to try to help someone. This is the beginners solution to problem:

123 reverse 321

12300 reverse to 00321 // bug problem with zero solved

I am still stuck with the problem: 00123 and output 32100 not 321

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class R_N{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter number:\n");
int x=input.nextInt();
int temp=x;
int z;
while(temp>0){
    z=temp%10;
        if(z==0){
            System.out.printf("%d",0);
        }else{
            System.out.printf("%d",z);
        }
    temp=temp/10;
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: When you input `00123` and read this as `int`, then the leading zeros are lost and the only thing you can do about this is: read it as `String`.

Comment: Do it all as a `String`. Don't do modulo operations, loop over the characers in the `String`.

Comment: Interesting: 'reverse random number from 1 to 9999` and example uses 23100

Comment: FredK..not really :-)..I was just describing how I run into this problem...if you look at this code, you'll see that there is not 'limitation', and also no checking entered number ( and who knows what sorts of potential bugs )...still beginner sorry

Comment: thanks Tom and Boris the Spider..I need more learning with String :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, that kind of tasks not about using strings or something. It's all about properly use modulo and div.
00123 trailing zeroes have sence only if it's text value. 123 is a number. So your program works well for your task. But your if(z==0) have no sence :)

Comment: Retardus... while I was trying to solve problem, question asks it self...ok I solve 123 to 321, than try 1230 and solve it ( from there is if (z==0)loop ...try above number with 0 without it :- ) ) ...and then A PROBLEM: I try 0321 reverse back to get starting number 1230 and couldn't do it for 3day's...than I start use Internet and you guys :-)

Comment: I thought I could do it with present knowledge but need more learning :-) )

Answer (score 0):

In order to reverse `00123` to `32100` you need to read the input as a `String`, then test if it contains only digits with a regular expression (such as `\\d+`), finally you could iterate it from the end printing each character. Something like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a number:\n");
System.out.flush();
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String x = input.nextLine().trim();
    if (x.matches("\\d+")) {
        // Iterate the input String in reverse order,
        for (int i = x.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Print each character
            System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        // Give the user a message ...
        System.out.printf("%s is not a number%n", x);
    }
    System.out.print("Please enter a number:\n");
    System.out.flush();
}
```